# UITableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths error

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have simple UITableView added into Storyboard like so:

```
UITableViewController * tvc = [[UITableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];

tvc.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine;
tvc.tableView.tableFooterView = [UIView viewWithClearBackgroundColor];

tvc.tableView.delegate = self;
tvc.tableView.dataSource = self;

tvc.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 0;
tvc.tableView.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight = 0;
tvc.tableView.estimatedSectionFooterHeight = 0;

self.tableView = tvc.tableView;
[self containerAddChildViewController:tvc toContainerView:self.tableViewContainerView useAutolayout:YES];
```

I want to add items to front of the table and I do it like this:

```
// Here I create cells, add them to section and calculate indexPaths
// which are stored in addedItems property

[self.tableView beginUpdates];

[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:addedItems withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

When I am scrolled at the top of the table, everything works as expected as you can see on the picture here:

[image: Add cells to front]

But if I am scrolled down, weird glitch appears:

[image]

I have tried to add `CATransaction` and also set `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` to NO.

Comment: Two things: 1.) Have you tried other animation styles than the automatic one for `insertRowsAtIndexPaths :`? 2.) The documentation for `performBatchUpdates:completion:` explicitly mentions that it performs a **single** animation when inserting **multiple** items.

Comment: 1) I have tried them all. 2) To replicate the error I have created completely empty project with just one button which is adding cells in front of the table. In my project cell is created when response from server is made, all the cells are created and then added in the single insertRowsAtIndexPaths.